# Data base migration from Informix to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, informix

I'm working on an analysis for a DB migration.

This DB was made on Informix, now the client wants use a free license data base.

This DB will be the central part of a banking system.

It may sound ridiculous, but the data base manager I think capable of handing this information is PostgreSQL.

I need your opinion!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  In particular, you need to pay attention to what is 'on topic' at SO, and asking for software recommendations are off topic: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._. That said, if you must discard Informix, then PostgreSQL is probably a fairly good choice.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, is 'BD' a consistent typo for DB, or does it have some other significance?

Comment: Why should that sound ridicolous that Postgres can handle that?

Comment: What is 'BD'? Comparing one database system to another is like comparing any other products - like cars, or cell phones, etc. A lot will depend on your needs and preferences. When it comes to cost, the license is only a small part of the total cost. What about the technical support and other services, the cost of migration, building skills, etc? Who are you going to call when your PostgreSQL system goes down or you accidentally do something wrong?

Comment: Sorry.
I'm copy and paste the question from spanish site where i post the same.
BD = Data Base.

@a_horse_with_no_name **That's precisely why that's my question.**
I'm not a DBA.

Comment: @PradeepNatarajan you're rigth, but i propose others like Oracle, unfortunately it must  be a free licence data base

Comment: @PradeepNatarajan: you call a company that offers paid support for Postgres. There are plenty that do that. Postgres  is absolutely up to the task

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is not a question of whether some service providers are capable but rather one of confidence and preference for the buyers. If you are buying a car, would you rather have the warranty and service contract from the manufacturer or a local mechanic? As a buyer, I know what I'd prefer! :)

Comment: @PradeepNatarajan: clearly the local mechanic. The manufacturers just rip you off. To get back on the topic: the support you get from the "manufacturer" of Postgres (e.g. through the mailing list) is **way** better then any experience I have with Oracle. I have reported 4 (real) bugs for Postgres over several years and all of them resulted in "I committed a patch - it will be available in the next minor release in 2 months". Most of the times I speak with Oracle the answer is "that's not a bug".

Comment: @PradeepNatarajan: additionally: the companies that offer paid support for Postgres are many times _also_ those that contribute and can fix a bug on their own. Just because you throw a ridiculous amount of many to a commercial software vendor does not guarantee you a good support.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I said, it is a question of preference and confidence. YMMV! The way a developer or DBA chooses a product is very different from how the CIO will go about it. My point being, there is no single right choice.

Comment: I am currently involved with a db migration project to pg running on Open SuSE LEAP, and so far were impressed with this db and the support.

Comment: @Green, la majoria de los desarrolladores Hispanos utilizamos la abreviación "db" para bases de datos.

Comment: thanks @FrankR. was an error.